# Como iniciar pelo genymotion no eclipse

Tags: android

Estou com dois emuladores de Android no meu eclipse, um que instalei e comecei a usar por default do eclipse, e outro instalei faz pouco tempo é o GenyMotion, porém quando vou executar minha aplicação ele não consegui iniciar pelo GenyMotion, acredito que esteja faltando alguma coisa de configuração do eclipse para iniciar pelo GenyMotion.

aceito sugestão.

Eu já instalei o emulador de Android no sistema operacional Windows.
Eu já instalei e plugin do GenyMotion no eclipse.
Eu já mostrei o caminho daonde o GenyMotion está instalado para eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Primeiramente crie um emulador no Genymotion e deixe-o executando.
2. Clique em botão direito no seu projeto > Run As > Run As Android
   Application:
3. Vai abrir uma janela com os dispositivos conectados ao seu
   computador e também os emuladores do genymotion que estiverem
   instalados.
4. Basta selecionar qual o dispositivo e clicar em Run.

[Aqui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YY6HKINmzmE) um tutorial de como instalar e configurar utilizando o eclipse.